# Using Perfmon counters only, how can I determine host CPU contention / overload?

Tags: exchange-2010, central-processing-unit, perfmon, vmotion, cas

I'm running VMWare and have an ESX host that is running at 100% CPU.  I also have two Exchange 2010 CAS servers that are running at 100% CPU,

Here are some additiona observations:

- The sum of the Processes tab is only a fraction of the total CPU.  It appears kernel time is not included when calculating process time.   (Top process was RPC client service at 40%)
- When I VMotion one server to a different host, the first VM immediately goes to 20% (normal load)
- When I VMotion the second server stays at 100% for a period of time, then goes to normal load after 2 minutes.

Image below

[image]

**Question**

What Perfmon metric would be most useful in determining contention within the CPU in this scenario?